# How to make input and label in-line using only css for bootstrap forms

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've tried all the suggestions on here, even using this link [Bootstrap horizontal-form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#horizontal-form). But nothing seems to work. I want to be try to just change the css, but at this point, anyway that works be great. I just want the label to be in the same line as the input. So basically all of the inputs and labels go across one line in one row. While also keeping the bootstrap form-control

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="" class="row py-2  rowRecordBorder" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="">
  <div class="app-col col-12 col-md-2 bottom-align ">
    <label class="active">Storage Phone #</label>
    <input type="tel" id="t887" name="t887" onchange="buildTejPost('t887', 1);" value="100 100 1000" class="form-control" onfocus="$('#t887').inputmask({'mask': '(999) 999-9999'});" onblur="phoneNumberCheck(this);" style="border-color: green;">
  </div>
  <div class="app-col col-12 col-md-2 bottom-align ">
    <label class="active">Storage Fax #</label>
    <input type="tel" id="t888" name="t888" onchange="buildTejPost('t888', 1);" value="000 000 0000" class=" form-control" onfocus="$('#t888').inputmask({'mask': '(999) 999-9999'});" onblur="phoneNumberCheck(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="app-col col-12 col-md-2 bottom-align ">
    <label class="active">Storage Pickup Time Open</label>
    <input type="text" id="t889" name="t889" onchange="buildTejPost('t889', 1);" value="9:00AM" class=" form-control" maxlength="128">
  </div>
  <div class="app-col col-12 col-md-2 bottom-align ">
    <label class="active">Storage Pickup Time Close</label>
    <input type="text" id="t890" name="t890" onchange="buildTejPost('t890', 1);" value="3:00PM" class=" form-control" maxlength="128">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to put a series of labels and form controls on a single horizontal row is to use `.form-inline`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#inline-forms

```html
<div class="form-inline">
    <label />
    <input />
    <label />
    <input />
    <label />
    <input />
    <label />
    <input />
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/edy16zx5/12/

Or you can use the Grid system to construct the columns, each of which contains a label and an input, just like how you've setup. In order to have the label and the input on one line, within each column, the trick is to have the column display as flex box as well:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap align-items-center">
        <label />
        <input />
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

[image]

You can reference Flex utilities here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/

- `d-flex`: display as flex, enables flexbox behaviors
- `flex-row`: set its direction to row
- `flex-nowrap`: no wrapping at all when overflow
- `align-items-center`: set center aligment for flex items

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/edy16zx5/16/

In both cases, you, as the developer, do need to consider how to place those input elements, especially when there are limited spaces! You can't just expect Bootstrap to automatically handle that for you.